# Pandas apply if-then statement to a matrix df

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Given the following df:

```
Name Id   v1 v2 v3 ...
A    1    1  3  5  ...
B    2    2  4  6  ...
```

I want to apply these condition for the columns v1 to v3...:

if value <= 2 then a

if 2< value <= 5 then b

if value > 5 then c

```
Name Id   v1 v2 v3 ...
A    1    a  b  b  ...
B    2    a  b  c  ...
```

I would use something like df[v1] = np.where(df[v1] <= 2, a, np.where(df[v1] <= 5, b, c)) then repeat the same for df[v2] df[v3]... Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `pd.cut`

```
df.iloc[:,2:]=df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda x : pd.cut(x,bins=[-np.inf,2,5,np.inf],labels = ['a','b','c']),1)
df
Out[817]: 
  Name  Id v1 v2 v3
0    A   1  a  b  b
1    B   2  a  b  c
```

Comment: Could not imagine cut to be of use here. Very nice.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have no idea why someone is doing downvote, but your answer own my vote :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
You're on the right track with `np.where`, but you can set everything at once instead of one column at a time.

```
v = df.iloc[:, 2:].values

df.iloc[:, 2:] = np.where(
        v <= 2, 'a', np.where((2 < v) & (v <= 5), 'b', 'c')
)    
df

  Name  Id v1 v2 v3
0    A   1  a  b  b
1    B   2  a  b  c
```

---

**Option 2**
If you're adventurous, there's also `np.select` -

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = np.select([v <= 2, (2 < v) & (v <= 5)], ['a', 'b'], default='c')
df

  Name  Id v1 v2 v3
0    A   1  a  b  b
1    B   2  a  b  c
```

Comment: very nice answer!  Thanks for all the details and options :)

Comment: @TylerNG Lol, just realised this is my #3000th answer. Congrats to us both!

Comment: I'm honored to be your 3000th.  Will be your 4000th soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to define the function you want to apply, then applymap it to the columns you're interested in. You can then set those same columns to be overridden by the new values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def function(value):
    if value <= 2:
        return 'a'

    if 2 < value <= 5:
        return 'b'

    if value > 5:
        return 'c'

df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].applymap(function)
```